# Building Custom Extentable Models

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a model called **client** with basic info such as first name, last name, email etc. If I want the user to be able to add another custom field (just for him) say **net worth** (a text field). This user will now be able to add net worth information to all his clients. Another user might want to add **call notes** to all of his clients.

How do I go about designing a model that can handle such custom additions from different users? And also, is there a specific name for what I am trying to do?

**Update:**

There are multiple accounts and each account has a set of clients. I'm thinking of using the ClientCharIndex model to keep track of all the extended fields and ClientCharAttribues model to store all the values.

```
class Client(Model):
   account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
   first_name = Model.CharField()
   last_name = Model.CharField()
   ...

class ClientCharIndex(Model):
   account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
   name = Model.CharField()

class ClientCharAttribues(Model):
   key = models.ForeignKey(ClientCharIndex)
   client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
   value = Model.CharField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is define a model with just key-value fields (and may be type) and have M2M or foreignkey relationship with `client` model.

Something like this:

```
class Client(Model):
  ...

class UserAttribues(Model):
   key = Model.CharField()
   value = Model.CharField()
   client = Model.ManyToManyField(Client)
```

With this you can add any key-value information to a client object and any number of them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the late reply! Does the updated model above make sense?

Comment: @drakej44, Don't know why you want intermediate `ClientCharIndex` model. But it seems okay.

Comment: it is to keep track of the fields added to each account, so as to show up as empty if there is no data on the client yet for that field. Does that make sense?